# How to resolve class name in static method when accessed through inherited class

Tags: c#, reflection

I think it is easiest to explain with an example.

Let's say I have the following:

```
public class A
{
    public static string DoWork() { return "working" + <here I want the class name>;}
}

public class B : A{}
```

Now if I do

```
A.DoWork();
```

I want the result "working < full type name of A >".

If I do

```
B.DoWork();
```

I want the same thing but with the full type name of B. Is it possible?

I know it is ugly to do something like this, but when working with certain CMS systems and you do want to write something useful you have to bend the rules.

Comment: do the method really needs to be static?

Comment: for static method your only bet is to use parameter to supply target type: `A.DoWork(this)` or `A.DoWork(A)`. You definitely need inheritance here to *automatically get info about current type*. Or dirty *tricks*, as vendettamit answer or possibly sort of *guessing* who is a caller, based on some rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want the same thing but with the full type name of B. Is it possible?

No. A call to `B.DoWork` is actually compiled into IL for a call to `A.DoWork` directly. There is no indication in the IL that you actually called `B.DoWork`, so you can't tell that without looking at the original source.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you for confirming it. I need "static abstract" :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic class

```
public class A<T>
{
    public static string DoWork() { return "working" + typeof(T).ToString(); }
}

public class B : A<B> { }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Jon's answer is correct, but your solution might actually help.

Comment: That won't work if you create another subclass of `B` though... it feels like an abuse of inheritance to me.

Comment: Yes it's not a good practice but it's work in the proposed case. The solution is to use a non static method